# What is the use of an accelerometer in a laptop that only has an SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, accelerometer

I'm referring to the HP ENVY 15 I7 7500U 12 512 FHD laptop that comes only with an SSD and has an accelerometer. I know the traditional use for an accelerometer is to protect hard drives that has a read/write head - so what would it be for in this case where an SSD isn't prone to the same problems?

Comment: Depending on which version it is, it is one of those "convertible" laptops that can have the screen flipped back completely and thus could be used to detect position and rotate the screen. It could also be simply because models of that system *can* have a mechanical HDD and it makes no economic sense to not have the sensor always fitted

Comment: Maybe it had other benefits, e.g. gaming

Comment: So if the laptop is damaged, logs based on the accelerometer can indicate that the laptop should not be freely replaced based on warranty (since warranty is designed to cover manufacture defect, not misuse)